# Write a program that prompts the user for first and last names. The program then prints last name and first

Tags: python

Write a program that prompts the user for first and last names. The program then prints last name and first. If user only enter one name, then give an error message. Please help for my if statement. Many Thanks

```
name = str(input("Your first and last names? "))
gap = name.find(" ")
name_length = len(name)
first = name[0:gap]
last = name[gap + 1 : name_length]
if name_length is 2:
    print("Name: ", last.upper(), ", ", first.capitalize(), sep = "")

else:
    print("ERROR: only one name found")
```

And these are what I except:

anGUS snodgrass

Your first and last names? Name: SNODGRASS, Angus

angus

Your first and last names? ERROR: only one name found

Comment: you're testing on `name_length`, you should test on `len(last)`. Also, you might want to  look into `str.split()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
name = input("Your first and last name: ").split(" ")
if len(name) == 2:
    print("Name: ", name[0].upper(), ", ", name[1].capitalize(), sep = "")
else:
    print("ERROR: unknown number of names found!")
```

Output:

```
 ==== RESTART: C:/Users/...
Your first and last name: anGUS snodgrass
Name: anGUS, snodgrass
>>> 
==== RESTART: C:/Users/...
Your first and last name: anGUS
ERROR: unknown number of names found!
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for an easy way around:

```
print("Enter your First and Last Name")
name = raw_input()
first,last = name.split()
print("Your FirstName:")
print(last.upper())
print("Your LasttName:")
print(first.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=input("Your first and last names : ").split()
if(len(x)<=1):
    print("name does not contain lastname or whole name is not mentioned ")
else:
    print(x[1]+" "+x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Input your First Name : ")

lname = input("Input your Last Name : ")

print ("Hello " + lname + " " + fname)



first_name = input('Please input your first name: ')
last_name = input('Please input your last name: ')
print(last_name + ', ' + first_name)
```